# Modify "The changes have been saved." message - Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

When modifying and saving account information, drupal shows "The changes have been saved." message and that comes from Drupal core user module. Is there a way to modify this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since status messages are shown using status-messages theme, you can write a preprocess function to alter them:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 *
 * @param $variables
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_status_messages(&$variables) {
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

  // Only handle user edit form
  if ($route === 'entity.user.edit_form' && isset($variables['message_list']['status'])) {
    $status_messages = $variables['message_list']['status'];
    foreach ($status_messages as $delta => $message) {
      // Find the message and replace it
      if ((string) $message === (string) t('The changes have been saved.')) {
        $variables['message_list']['status'][$delta] = t('Your message text');
      }
    }
  }
}
```